# Can't login after AMD video driver installation

Tags: 14.04, login, login-screen, amd-graphics

I installed AMD Radeon Software Crimson Edition 15.12 driver to Ubuntu 14.04.5.

And now I can't login: there is no any error, it tries to login and then return to login menu.

I tried to login via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but get an error "incorrect login". Credentials are 100% correct!

What should I do with this?

Comment: Please add information about your system setup, is it just a single partition?

Comment: Go Grub menu > Advanced Options >  Recovery Mode > root option >  `cat /var/log/auth.log` . What does it say about your login tryout?